# Parse 2.000,00 to 2000 and 2.000,15 to 2000.15

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am struggling with formatting numbers in java.

My input format looks like this (and I cannot change that): *2.000,15*
and the output should look like this: *2000.15*

In case of only 0 after the comma the output should look like this: *2000*

The input is given as a String.

I've already tried to use a `DecimalFormat` but this only leads to `IllegalArgumentException`

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
return decimalFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(characteristicValue));
```

Comment: Is your input number format set to EU and output set to US?

Comment: How do I do/check that?

Comment: Try Locale.GERMAN? They use comma as a decimal separator. Or whichever locale the input file came from.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(characteristicValue)` will use some hardcoded formats that don't handle a comma as the decimal separator. Instead you'd need to use another `DecimalFormat` to _parse_ the input string (one that uses a comma as the decimal separator).

Comment: @glethien See my response below on input/output number formats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

give this a try:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        try {
            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(fmt.parse("2.000,15").toString());
            System.out.println(bd.toString()); // output: 2000.15
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            //ex handling
        }
```

Comment: Ideally, you'd also use a NumberFormat for the correct output format instead of relying on `toString()`, but the input parsing is the right direction.

Comment: @ArvidHeise yes, output via a format object with the desired locale would be a reliable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Choose a number format that uses dot-separated thousands-place separators.
2. Set the minimum significant figures for the decimal (fraction) place.

There is no need to set-up a format that already exists in Java's SDK.

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class FormattingNumbers {
    static NumberFormat inputFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    static NumberFormat outputFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);

    static {
        inputFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        outputFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String[] numbers = { "2.000,00", "2.000,15" };

        for (String number : numbers) {
            System.out.println(outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(number)));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2,000.00
2,000.15
```

**Note:** Here is a list of [countries using decimal comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma).

Answer (score 0):

You had the right tool, but you don't need to get an instance of `DecimalFormat`, you can just create your own.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String pattern = "###,###.###";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

        String format = decimalFormat.format(2000.15);
        System.out.println(format);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives me IllegalArgumentException as the input is a String and Double.parseDouble also gives an Exception.

Comment: is `characteristicValue` a double ? Could you give an example of what it could be ?

Comment: "2.000,15" - It is a string